# Exressjs: how to get https server address and port?

Tags: node.js, express, https

How can I get https server address and port with expressjs?

With http:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log(server.address());
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

result:

> { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 } Example app
>   listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000

But with https:

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    console.log('Started!');

    var host = https.address;
    var port = https.port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

result:

```
Example app listening at http://undefined:undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

may be this link is helpful to you
https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/